# Java stream. Only once

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a way to make my stream iterate only once, after my filter is true?

Example:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(ele -> ele.isBlue())
    .map(Element::getSomething)
    .collect(toList());
```

Say I have many elements in my list, but only one is blue. And I know that only one is blue, but I dont know where is it. And for arguments sake, lets say that isBlue() is a slow method, so I want to stop when it hits once.

Comment: `findFirst().orElse(null)` instead of calling `collect`. If you use `parallelStream` and it's guaranteed that there is only one element in the stream, you can use `findAny().orElse(null)` instead.

Comment: Since streams are lazy you just need `filter(..).findFirst().orElse(..whatever)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for only one element, instead of `collect()` use `findFirst()`/`findAny()`.

```
Optional<Something> s = list.stream()
    .filter(ele -> ele.isBlue())
    .map(Element::getSomething)
    .findAny();
```

You then either get an `Optional` containing the single blue element, or an empty `Optional`.

There's no difference between `findFirst()` and `findAny()` in simple streams, only when parallelism is involved (where `findFirst()` returns deterministically the first element, and `findAny()` will return any single suitable element it finds).

Answer (score 5):

You could still `collect`, but with a `limit`:

```
list.stream()
   .filter(ele -> ele.isBlue())
   .map(Element::getSomething)
   .limit(1)
   .collect(toList());
```

Comment: This is useful if you do additional work requiring a collection, so you don't need to put the contents of an `Optional` into a new list manually.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I'm gonna try the findFirst() variant first.

Comment: @Kayaman: though, `findFirst().map(Collections::singletonList).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)` isn’t so much more complicated and has some neat properties…

Comment: @Holger certainly, there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth understanding that Stream pipelines are driven by the last step, the *terminating operation*.

Instead of thinking of a stream producer pushing items down a conveyor belt, into a waiting consumer, think of the terminating operation pulling items -- the producer adds a new item when asked.

In your example, the terminating operation is `collect(collector)` - this pulls items from the previous step until there are no more, submitting each element to the collector. The previous step is `map()`, but it works on demand -- it only pulls an item from the step before that -- `filter()` -- when `collect()` asks for another item.

`findFirst()` is another terminating operation. It asks the previous step for one item -- the first item in the stream. So if we change your example to ...

```
list.stream()
   .filter(ele -> ele.isBlue())
   .map(Element::getSomething)
   .findFirst(toList());
```

... the `findFirst()` pipeline step will read from the `map()` step exactly once. If it gets an item, it will return `Optional.of(item)`.

`map()` in turn will read from `filter()` exactly once. `filter()` will repeatedly read from the stream until `isBlue()` is true, and return that.

If `filter()` reaches the end of its input stream without finding a match, it will indicate end-of-stream. This will propagate down the pipeline, `findFirst()` will notice end-of-stream, and return `Optional.empty()`.

There is also a `findAny()`, which will return an arbitrary matching item. This may return faster if part of the pipeline gets parallelised -- or it may allow a pipeline to be parallelised when having an order-sensitive step would preclude it.

Look at the `Stream` Javadoc to see all the terminating operations.